# Prevent tar from overwriting tarball

Tags: linux, tar

I accidentally ran the same command twice:

```
tar --remove-files -cf ../2019-09.tar *2019-09-*
```

The second invocation replaced the tarball containing my data with an empty one, even though it died with the error messages:

```
tar: *2019-09-*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

It would be nice if tar didn't create a new tarball until it had something to put in it, but I imagine that change would break some existing scripts.

I was hoping there was a command-line option I could pass to tar via bashrc to get a warning before overwriting existing files in the future (like `alias mv='mv -i'`), but I can't find one.

Is there a good way to disarm this footgun?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. `tar` does not provide an option for that. As many other commands (dd, mkfs.*, cpio,...) , it supposes you know what you are doing and can destroy data if you do something wrong.

If if you find yourself doing this type of `tar` often, you could wrap the behaviour you want `tar` to have in a shell script. For example:

```
~/bin/archive_and_remove tar_file files
```

Inside the script I can think of three ways to protect you from overwriting the tarfile:

Check if the filename exists before doing the tar (no --remove-files):

```
test -f TARFILENAME || tar ... FILES
```

Do the `tar` and remove the files if it succeds (no --remove-files):

```
tar ... FILES && rm FILES
```

Protect the file once it has finished (with --remove-files). You can use `&&` because  `tar` should not remove FILES if there is an output error:

```
tar --remove-files ... FILES && chown u-w TARFILENAME
```